# Push vertically resizable Div to bottom of wrapper. How?

Tags: css, html

First of all, hello all.
This problem is driving me to insanity so I hope for a simple solution

Here is [an image of what I wanted originally](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3276/divcolumns.png).

But I didnt want to use hacks to get Box 1 and (Box 2+Box 3) to expand with each other. So I will just use a background color on the wrapper instead so its not noticeable that they have different heights.

This is what I have now:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    background:         #000;
    width:              50%; 
    float:              left;
}

#box1 {
    background:         #FF0012;
    width:              65%;
    float:              left;
}

#box2 {
    background:         #141; 
    width:              35%;
    margin-left:        65%;    
}


#box3 {
    background:#AA1232;
    width:              35%;
    margin-left:        65%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

 <div id="wrapper">

  <div id="box1">

  </div>

  <div id="box2">

  </div>

  <div id="box3">

  </div>

 </div>

</body>
```

If you wonder why I dont use `float: right;` on Box 2 and 3 its because if Box 1 is lower than Box 2 then Box 3 will float under Box 1 instead of under Box 2.

Problem:
1. Fix Box 3 to the bottom of the wrapper
2. When rows are inserted in Box 3 and Box 2, they shouldn't overflow - expand the wrappers height instead (as it does with the code i posted)

If I use `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on Box 3 then it will overflow Box 2 when rows are inserted and Box 3 gets too heigh.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: When you say resizable do you mean the user can resize it or that it will get taller with more text?

Comment: That it will get taller with more text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why it drives you crazy - you are trying to solve table problem by un-table means. Why?

I tought myself to recognize table functionality: when I want independed pieces of content to share a common vertical and horizontal edge, it usually means I want a table.

Edit: to achieve that using table you need to 1) use rowspan to make box 1 span two rows and 2) vertically align contents of box 3 to make sure it is always at the bottom.

See, for example, the HTML that illustrates rowspan [here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/tables/advancedtables.html#ROWSPAN). It is almost what you want, just get rid of table borders and add valign="bottom" to the third cell.

Comment: I like to stay away from tables as much as the next guy for layout, but the requirements of this question require a table.

Comment: Well, as Im new to this I havnt used tables for structuring a site before. What would the code look like that make a table do what I want? ( With Box3, or table cell 3, always is pushed towards the bottom when content is added in either table cell 1 or 2 )

Comment: HTML property of cell valign="bottom" takes care of that.

Comment: Since this is not tabular data, a table shouldn't be used according to The Law, but because those CSS folks failed to give us a way to easily do grid layouts, fsck it!  Use a table.  (though I hope somebody have a better solution)

Comment: Thanks for answering to all. Are there any common problems using a table that I should know about (seeing as everybody hates them so much)? E.g. Will it validate fine? Can I have DIVs in each cell? Other troubles I might run into?

Comment: One more thing. I added valign="bottom" to the third cell. It works except for one case. When Cell 1 contains many more rows than the others. I need Cell 3 to only be as "high" as it has rows. I uploaded an image of the scenario here: http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/5066/tabletest.png 
In other words: Cell 3 should be the smallest cell in this scenario.
Is it fixable?

Comment: That is why I told you to get rid of table borders. Your content is placed correctly, so if box 1 is higher than box 2 plus box 3, who cares where the white space goes? If you have to have borders, put a div in each cell and border then. I guess you can get exactly the original picture by completely bordering box 1, not bordering box 2 and having all but left borders on box 3.

Comment: As to table hate, read, for example, this SO discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313468/why-is-using-tables-for-website-layout-such-an-evil.

Comment: I understand. I put a div in each cell and now its exactly as I want it. Thank you. I wasted SO much time trying to get the DIVs to work.