# put asp.net controls in different places on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I want to put controls on the page where I want for example grid view on the left side
and pairs of text boxes and labels on the right side. how could i do that?
because when i try to drag and drop it just puts text boxes and labels under the grid view or up the view (it sticks to the grid view)

Comment: The easy way is to add an html grid/table to the page and use the rows/columns cells and align.

Comment: I think you should learn basics of HTML before you start with ASP.NET and controls like GridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the Layout of your page :

1.) Using CSS. by use of `<div>`, `<span>` tags etc

2.) Using Tables

Using tables for page layout is actually debatable and many recommend not to use it. Anyhow thats totally a different question. Still check this: [Why is using tables for website layout such an evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313468/why-is-using-tables-for-website-layout-such-an-evil)

***`Using CSS:`***

**Page Markup:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="content-left"></div>
        <div id="content-main"></div>
        <div id="content-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
        width:900px;
        margin:0px auto;
        border:1px solid #bbb;
        padding:10px;
    }
#header {
        border:1px solid #bbb;
        height:80px;
        padding:10px;
    }
    #content {
        margin-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
    }
    #content div {
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid #bbb;
        float:left;
    }
    #content-left {
        width:180px;
    }
    #content-main {
        margin-left:10px;
        width:500px;
    }
    #content-right {
        margin-left:10px;
        width:134px;
    }
    #footer {
        float:left;
        margin-top:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:10px;
        border:1px solid #bbb;
        width:878px;
    }
    #bottom {
        clear:both;
        text-align:right;
    }
```

**`*Output:*`**

[image]

***`Using tables:`***

```
 <table width="500" border="0">
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
          <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
       </td>
   </tr>    
   <tr>
       <td style="background-color:#FFD700;width:100px;">
          <b>Menu</b><br>
             HTML<br>
             CSS<br>
            JavaScript
      </td>
      <td style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:200px;width:400px;">
          Content goes here</td>
   </tr>    
   <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFA500;text-align:center;">
            Copyright Note</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

***`Output:`***

[image]

Refer below links for more examples:

- http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3642151/CSS-Layouts-Without-Tables.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp